# Why is my LG TV not listed under under HomeKit security accessories?

Tags: security, homekit

My understanding of one of the benefits of adding a device to HomeKit (and part of the definition of a HomeKit compatible device) was that I could secure it using HomeKit by controlling what connections it could make to the internet. Other devices behave this way (e.g. my Philips bridge or all of my Belkin outlets), but my LG [OLED55CXPUA](https://www.lg.com/us/tvs/lg-oled55cxpua-oled-4k-tv) TV does not appear there, and acts as if it can freely connect to the internet as it wishes

Why is my HomeKit compatible LG TV not listed under under HomeKit security accessories?

Comment: That's not something that homekit does for all devices. I have some bulbs added to homekit, all it does is relay commands to the bulb manufacturer's server.

Comment: @Scottmeup There's no mention of any exceptions in [Apple's description of the feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210544). As described it applies to any HK certified device.

Comment: `As described it applies to any HK certified device` I don't see mention of `all features available on all HK enabled devices` or words to that effect, could you highlight the relevant section for me?

Comment: @Scottmeup As you say "it applies to any HK certified device", so it should apply to any HK certified TV.

Comment: I was quoting you, I don't believe that makes it a fact? Can you show me on the linked document where it says that these features apply to all HK certified devices?

Comment: @Scottmeup Are you saying that, reading Apple’s description, you come to a different conclusion?

Comment: I've made it clear what I've seen (or haven't) in the document.